# Cocapods Updating Firebase instead of installing v 11 reverts to old version v3.6

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cocoapods

I have inherited a project that has not been updated for a while. It uses Firebase SDK with Coapods. Latest version of Cocapods currently is Version 10.0.0 - October 10, 2022 ([https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios][1])

My Podfile looks like this

> platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'AppName' do

```
# Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
use_frameworks!

# Pods for AppName
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
```

As you can see I do not limit versions with ~> notation.
When I run pod update Firebase in terminal I get

```
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing Firebase 3.6.0
Installing Firebase 7.3.0 (was 3.6.0)
Installing GoogleUtilities 1.3.2
Installing GoogleUtilities 7.8.0 (was 1.3.2)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Pod installation complete! There are 29 dependencies from the Podfile and 65 total pods installed.
```

So why does it not update to the version 11?
Why is this line here -> Installing Firebase 3.6.0 ?

Also I get bunch of warnings like:

```
[!] Unable to read the license file `LICENSE` for the spec `Firebase (7.3.0)`
[!] Unable to read the license file `LICENSE` for the spec `GoogleUtilities (7.8.0)`
[!] Unable to read the license file `LICENSE` for the spec `Firebase (7.3.0)`
[!] Unable to read the license file `LICENSE` for the spec `GoogleUtilities (7.8.0)`
[!] [Xcodeproj] Generated duplicate UUIDs
```

How do I make it to update to version 11? And without bunch of warnings? Any idea where to start?
[1]: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios

Comment: Switch to SPM it will make the process much simpler

Comment: @SimpleApp try deleting podfile.lock file and the updating pods

Comment: There is probably something else in the Podfile that is incompatible with Firebase 10.x. The `Podfile.lock` should provide the details.